# other than x32dbg, is there a more friendly way to check functions, their args and their return values on runtime?

Tags: ida, assembly, dynamic-analysis, debug

atm I'm using ida and x32dbg, when I find a function that interests me, I set a breakpoint on x32dbg, however, I'm not good enough at assembly to know everything from a function just from looking at the registers and whatnot. When I think a function may be something, I hook it, but it's an annoying process.

So is there an easier way to debug dll functions at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Api Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) is a great tool to hook api's, watch parameters and return values and optionally modify them before/after call.

> API Monitor is a free software that lets you monitor and control API calls made by applications and services. Its a powerful tool for seeing how applications and services work or for tracking down problems that you have in your own applications.

[image: Main View]

[image: Summary View with Syntax Highlighting]